# How to properly pass values through in jquery / ajax calls

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I've been creating a web app and one example of something it does is create golf rounds. Everything I've done works but I have been doing some testing and the way im passing variables through to my ajax call means the user could update anyone's round.

Currently I have a table that shows you your round and you can select the view button which will open a modal form to show details of that round.

**This is my HTML**

```
<button
  type="button"
  id="view-round"
  class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-square btn-skew pull-right" 
  attr-id="39"
>View</button>
```

**This is my jquery**

```
$('body').on('click', '#view-round', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('attr-id');
    $.post('/dashboard/pages/golf/round/ajax.php?action=load', {id: id}, function(response) {
      //code in here
    }
   });
```

You can see from this that I'm passing through the round id via the attribute on the button "attr-id".

What I'm asking is can I put this variable somewhere someone couldn't edit it via the developer console etc.

I'm currently changing the ajax calls so that you can only update/look at your own records but really I'd like to stop it from being changed all together.

Comment: Essentially: no.   You ned to provide server-side security, possibly with a security token that is assigned to your user and must be passed with POST requests to see which records that user can view/update, *server side*.

Comment: Note that your JavaScript seems to be missing (at least) a closing parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, was a botched copy and paste as only copied to the top of the post request

Comment: @freedomn-m So I'm planning to implement that kind of logic as it's not live yet. So is there no way we can asign any sort of id without it being unchangable? no worries if not but thank you for your help :)

Comment: Pretty much anything the browser can do in javascript, the user can do the same via the console / browser dev tools.

Comment: You could change to a `guid` "id" instead of an integer - or other, similar, non-guessable generated id.  Then your user can't just do `$('#view-round'").attr("attr-id", 1)` as they would need to know that guid.

Comment: @freedomn-m I just went with what you said about server side authentication by giving permissions based on fields against their user that data stays in the database so can't be altered by the users.